# OWIN ValidateClientRedirectUri

Tags: c#, owin

I override ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context) method of class OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.

When the redirect uri check fails, I set the error in the context. I was expecting the browser to redirect to the error uri I set in the context. But, it does not.

I want the user to be redirected to the error page, when the clientRedirectUri check fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the method

```
public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
```

and after validating the redirect uri, if the uri is found to be invalid.

Write

```
context.Rejected();
context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect(errUrl);
```

and if the uri is valid, then

```
context.Validated(context.RedirectUri);
```